# ¿Cómo puedo configurar un mensaje de navegador?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un pequeño archivo .html para detectar cuando un usuario cierra la página web(ya sea cerrando la pestaña, cerrando el navegador o pulsando alt+f4), el problema es que no me muestra el mensaje que espero el cual es: 'Estás por cerrar la página, cuidado!', en su lugar aparece el mensaje por defecto del navegador, probé el código en google chrome Versión 77.0.3865.120 (Build oficial) (64 bits) y firefox v71.0 (64-bit), estoy con Ubuntu 18.04.Gracias de antemano.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            var e = e || window.event;
            if (e) {
                e.returnValue = 'Estás por cerrar la página, cuidado!';
            }
        }
    </script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Detectar</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>DETECTAR EL CIERRE DE LA PÁGINA WEB - INTENTA CERRAR LA PÁGINA</h1>            
</body>
</html>
```

P.D.: Se debe hacer al menos un click en la página para que funcione la detección.

Comment: mira este link ya un usuario lo pudo solucionar, espero te ayude. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38879742/is-it-possible-to-display-a-custom-message-in-the-beforeunload-popup

Comment: Hola aquí hay información de por que no se muestra el mensaje en google Chrome. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480

Answer (score 6):

Lo mas sencillo sería cambiar la forma en la que se entrega el mensaje, básicamente seria:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
            var e = e || window.event;
            if (e) {
                e.returnValue = alert('Estás por cerrar la página, cuidado!');
            }
        }
    </script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Detectar</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>DETECTAR EL CIERRE DE LA PÁGINA WEB - INTENTA CERRAR LA PÁGINA</h1>            
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <a href="javascript:finestraSecundaria('ladin.php')">Haz clic Aqui</a>
<script language=javascript>
function finestraSecundaria (url){
    var ventana = window.open(url, '_blank');
    // Hay que esperar a que se cargue la página
    ventana.onload = function() {
        // Ya se cargó la página y se puede asignar el evento final
        ventana.onunload = function() {
            console.log('Se cerró la ventana o el usuario cambió de página');
        }
    };
}
</script>
```

Esto es más sencillo y efectivo.

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionar, **aunque no lo hará para Opera**.

```
var miEvento = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var compIE = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// hace compatible IE7, IE8.

miEvento(compIE, function(e) { // Para >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmaMsg = 'Estás por cerrar la página, cuidado!';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmaMsg;
            return confirmaMsg;
    });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, he estado leyendo documentación sobre el evento "onbeforeunload", y parece que retiraron la opción de modificar los mensajes, de todos modos intentaré hacer la prueba con otras versiones de navegador para confirmarlo.